# Instant get method form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have input:

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="1" max="20" name="kredai" class="form-control" placeholder="Kaina, eurais (privaloma)"></input>
```

How can I make, that when client fills this input, it would go to

```
 http://some.web/cost.php?kredai=5
```

(where 5 is value from input) and shows result from cost.php bellow input?

sorry for my english.

Comment: are you looking for form tag with action=" http://some.web/cost.php " method= " GET "

Comment: I have php code. I think I need javascript, to show cost.php content when input is filled by user

Comment: you mean ajax request to cost.php when you type something in your input box ?

Comment: Yes. When input is filled or user changed its content, bellow it show info from cost.php?kredai='input value'

Comment: what output you get if you hit this ? http://some.web/cost.php?kredai=5

Comment: it's simple php code. includes config.php and
`<?=$_GET['kredai'] * $uz_eura?>`

Comment: check this https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: thanks! its working now

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found solution:

HTML:

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="1" name="kredai" id="kredai" class="form-control" placeholder="Kaina, eurais (privaloma)"></input>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#kredai').on('input',function(e){
    var value = "./assets/cost.php?cost=" + $("#kredai").val();
    $.get( value, function( data ) {
        $( ".result" ).html( data );
    });
});
```

Thanks for help everyone!

Answer (score -2):

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="1" max="20" name="kredai" class="form-control" placeholder="Kaina, eurais (privaloma)" action="cost.php" method="get"></input>
```

and in the cost.php file:

```
$kredai = $_GET['kredai'];
```

Comment: Not a lot. As far as I can tell, everything added here is invalid and won't do anything.

Comment: No.. I have php code. I think I need javascript, to show cost.php content when input is filled by user